# FirefoxOS update 1.1 to 1.3 in LG D300?

Tags: mozilla, firefox-os

So i have my LG D300 that can be called as LG Fireweb too
I see the other devices like geeksphone have 1.2 or 1.3v, have a way to update LG D300 too?

I'm googling like wildfire and i found nothing, someone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Wtkd, those devices have their bootloader locked by their manufacturers, which means that you have to wait until LG releases their versions of Firefox OS 1.2 or 1.3

The other possibility, is to wait until someone figures out how to unlock the bootloader and flash a custom image (Something similar to what happens with Android phones).

As a heads up, LG and Alcatel (Manufacturers of Firefox OS phones), have 6 months to update the system, and that is a contractual clause. So don't worry, they will release it soon. If you want to see what's new about 1.2, take a look [here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/notes/1.2/).

As a reminder, v1.3 is still in it's early days, and is not available for any of the commercial devices. Geeksphone produces devices that were meant to be Developing tools, and thats why releases comes faster for them.

Hope I was able to help.

Cheers

Comment: Cool, i know about that but i see some guides "upadate your geeksphone to 1.2 etc" prob in my device i need to wait, i'm trying to dev an firefox OS game with just js/css3/html5 if you are developing something to firefoxOS and you can gimme some tips feel free for this :)
thanks for answer o/

Comment: Thats awesome. Firefox os certainly needs more games. I would suggest you take a look into rob nyman's boilerplate apps that can be found on github. Also, you might want to search for an app that I've done that utilizes very simply html+css+js coding. It's called Who Am I and is also available on github. Unfortunately, at the time I do not have something game related, but feel free to join our irc (irc.mozilla.org), there is plenty of rooms and people to help you out. Good luck!