# Use blutetooth API in Firefox OS?

Tags: bluetooth, asp.net-web-api, firefox-os

I'm creating an app that needs to connect the firefox os to another dispositive using the bluetooth API, but this API is just allowed to Certified Apps, has somehow to allow an Sandbox mode and allow the installation only in my cellphone?

Comment: You could be able to add the "type": "certified" to your manifest and add the "bluetooth":{} permission to the manifest.  Push the app to your phone using the app manager.  This will require at least Firefox OS 1.2 to test.

Comment: But i have a LG Fireweb with Firefox OS 1.1! There is another method?

Comment: Take a look at the response on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805958/firefoxos-update-1-1-to-1-3-in-lg-d300

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you can create a certified application, but you won't be able to publish it to the Firefox OS Marketplace: it's good for internal deployment with the App Manager. If you want to use Bluetooth API, and make your application publicly available, it's not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of web activities as well but that will open the Gaia's bluetooth app for file transfer.

I heard before from someone that we will be able to use Bluetooth API in v1.3 but I guess it's still not accessible. Let's wait for v1.4.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is 2.2 will expose Bluetooth API, so you could use it at the end of 2015 when FxOS 2.2 device hit the market...